# Fn+search broken on Dell Inspiron

Tags: kubuntu, dell, kde, 19.10, function-keys

When i press FN+SEARCH on my laptop (FN+F9) the KDE dekstop freaks out (opens the run menu (ktunner), same as ALT+F2, closes it and opens it several times VERY fast), after that the META or SUPER key doesnt open the Kickoff menu until i reboot or kwin --replace. All other FN keys work as intended. Is there a fix for that ?

Hardware: Canonical certified DELL Inspiron 15 3585 Ryzen 5 2500U Vega 8

Software: Kubuntu 19.10 (latest available updates as of 2020-03-22)

I used xev to see what it does, It seems it does this, and does it A LOT:

```
MotionNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 60253, (142,31), root:(142,64),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
```

Comment: I think that `MotionNotify` has to do with the movement of the touchpad pointer/cursor and nothing to do with pressing `Fn+F9`. What do you see in `System Settings` > `Shortcuts` > `Global shortcuts` > `Run command`? On my Dell Inspiron 15-3567 with Kubuntu 18.04, pressing `Fn+F9` does bring up the krunner window but it doesn't misbehave. What happens if you just don't use `Fn+F9` and instead stay with `Alt+F2`?

Comment: ALT-F2 works as intended, settings you mentioned list: ALT+Space > ALT+F2 and execute command from clipboard ALT+SHIFT+F2

Comment: I couldn't find out where `Fn+F9` is set or how to disable it. I prefer to have `Alt+Space` to launch krunner and have never used `Fn+F9` until I read your question. If everything else is working fine, just avoid using `Fn+F9`.

Comment: But i accidentally hit it sometimes and it causes havoc, is there anything i can do to diagnose/troubleshoot it ? or disable its functionality ? The BIOS only gives me an option to disable FN keys ENTIRELY...

Comment: Follow this: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/fn1wf1/. Maybe someone there can help.

Comment: Is there a way i can provide more info ? That key combo is real annoying

Answer (score 0):

System Settings > Shortcuts > Global shortcuts > Run command

Disable all default shortcuts

I suggest remapping to ALT+=

Comment: EDIT: Not working after reboot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem you describe isn't because of something fundamentally wrong with your system (see later), here's one workaround:

- Install `xdotool` using, in this order,

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt full-upgrade`
  - `sudo apt install xdotool`
- Open *System Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts*. In there,

  - create a new global shortcut of type Command/URL
  - Name the shortcut whatever you like
  - In the Action tab, enter exactly `xdotool key shift`
  - In the Trigger tab, press the <kbd>Input</kbd> button and then press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>
  - You should get a pop-up complaining that the shortcut is in use. Click the <kbd>Reassign</kbd> button and then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> (in the lower right corner of the System Settings window).

From now on, whenever you press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, nothing obvious will happen and this setting *should* survive a reboot.

---

If the change you made doesn't survive a reboot, I suspect you have other problems as well. One possibility is that one or more files in your home folder or its subfolders are owned not by you but by `root`. You can check with this command which may take a little while to complete: `cd ~ && find . '!' -user $USER -ls`. If you get back just the prompt, that means nothing is owned by `root`. If you get any hits, it's your job to evaluate each one and act appropriately.

Another possibility is that there's something else wrong with your system. Do you have the same problem if you create a new user?